# Pokemon Go - One apple ID, two Iphones

Tags: pokemon-go

EDIT: There seems to be a lot of confusion in m question so let me pose this again.

My brother and I have separate APPLE ID's. I recently made a new Apple ID so I can download Pokemon GO and all was well, I signed out of the new Apple ID and went back to my own Apple ID and it worked perfectly (note: Pokemon GO has a different G-MAIL for everyone). The next day, my brother went onto the Apple ID that I created new yesterday and downloaded the APP as well and then logged back on to his account. At the moment we are both playing Pokemon GO, there will be an update next week; can we both log onto the APPLE ID that I made and update the app? Or can the update only work on one phone?

Original: I have a concern, I recently made a new gmail account in order to make a apple ID in a new country so I can download Pokemon GO - recently my brother found out the details and he signed into the account I made on his phone and downloaded the application as well. When the time calls for an update for the app, are we both allowed to update the application on our different phones or will it cause problems?

Thank you very much

Comment: Are you saying your brother is using your old account, or you are both using the same account?

Comment: I think this is a super user or ask different question.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying

Comment: No no, my brother and I previously had different Apple ID's but we downloaded PokemonGo on the same apple ID but have different Gmails for the game itself

Answer (score 1):

**As long as you are using different google accounts for Pokemon Go the fact that you are using the same apple ID will have no impact whatsoever on the game.**

---

If you have changed Apple accounts since you downloaded the app then you may run into a problem when the app updates as [it will ask for the password of the account is was downloaded under](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/135930/app-store-asking-for-other-apple-id-when-updating-apps).

You can simply delete the app and redownload it under your current apple ID in order to have it under your current Apple ID instead of the old one. The fact that two people are using the same apple ID won't have any impact. It only matters that you have changed it since downloading it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,
but I mean I made the account first and then he went on the account and downloaded Pokemon and now we both went back to our original accounts. The game will be updated soon, can we both update without problems? Of course we are both seperate levels and content - my question is more on technicality.

Comment: @WorriedGuest oh, so you downloaded pokemon go with account 'a' but now you are logged in to account 'b'? I think in that case it will ask you for the password of account 'a' in order to update. You can just delete the app and then redownload it under account 'b' so that it is not associated with account a at all.

Comment: Its not available in his country yet. When there is an Update you need Account B's password.

Comment: Ok I get that, we both have account b's password; so can we both go on account b and update the app or will app store only allow the app to be updated for one iphone? That is my only question <3

Comment: @WorriedGuest if you enter the password you can both update no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will be both be able to log into the other Apple ID to update the app. Apple supports having more than one device for an account. Right now I have the same Apple ID signed in on an iPad and an iPhone, and I can log in and out of my US Apple ID to update the Pokemon Go app if I need to.

Comment: You'd just need to sign out of your current Apple ID in your Settings and sign in to the new one first, Update, then sign out and back into your usual one.